# Error starting up Eureka Client with Spring Boot 2.4.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am developing an application using Spring Boot 2.4.1 and Eureka. I achieved to start up the Eureka Server, but with the Eureka Client I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
```

The pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>some.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artefact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>some-name</name>
    <description>some-description</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The following is the application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: @project.artifactId@

logging:
  file.name: ../logs/@project.artifactId@.log
  file.max-size: 10MB

server:
  port: 8080
```

And the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.something")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SpigaConnectorServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpigaConnectorServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    class ServiceInstanceRestController {

        @Autowired
        private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

        @RequestMapping("/service-instances/{applicationName}")
        public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(
                @PathVariable String applicationName) {
            return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the server pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.ptesa.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>pt-eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>pt-eureka-server</name>
    <description>Registry and discovery of services</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The application.yml of the server:

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

And the class that start the server:

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(com.ptesa.cloud.EurekaServerApplication.class);
    }

}
```

When using Spring Boot version 2.3.7.RELEASE I don't have this problem. The application starts almost normally. Just get the following warning:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/Jucaalpa/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Is there a way to run Eureka Client with Spring Boot 2.4.1. Do you think it's better to use Spring Boot 2.3.7 because of compatibilities issue like the one I am having?

Thanks you.

Comment: share the client config code

Comment: I just shared the application.yml and the main class. The project doesn't have more classes

Comment: you mentioned that you are seeing error for client, but shared server code and config

Comment: OK. I uploaded the server files.

Comment: not sure , I see `@EnableEurekaServer` twice. shouldn't the client have `@EnableDiscoveryClient`? https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy and paste error.

Comment: I just saw something important I missed in the stack trace: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4. I am gonna answer the question with the solution I found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that adding the following dependency, the problem doesn't occur.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

May help: I changed the project SDK version from 16 to 1.8 and the problem disappeared! (in Intellij go to Project Structure)

Answer (score 0):

In **client yaml file**, add the below config

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```